# merging plots from 2 models from sjplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I need two models' plots combined into one graph, as seen in the image below. model 1 estimate's top line and model 2 estimates's bottom line.
I create the graph using one model, but I'm not sure how to incorporate an estimate from another model.

[image]

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(sjlabelled)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(pscl)
library(boot)


zinb <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age,
                 link="logit",
                 dist = "negbin",
                 data=caterpillor)



summary(zinb)
plot_model(zinb, type="est")


zinb <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                 link="logit",
                 dist = "negbin",
                 data=caterpillor)

summary(zinb)
plot_model(zinb, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))



############ second model#######


zinb_sub <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age,
                     link="logit",
                     dist = "negbin",
                     data=subset(caterpillor, country=="eng"))



summary(zinb_sub)
plot_model(zinb_sub, type="est")



zinb_sub2 <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                 link="logit",
                 dist = "negbin",
                 data=subset(caterpillor, country=="eng"))

summary(zinb_sub2)

plot_model(zinb_sub2, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))
```

Data:

```
caterpillor=structure(list(id = 1:100,
               age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                               .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
               sex = structure(c(2L, 
                                 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 1L, 1L),
                               .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"),
               country = structure(c(1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                     2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                     3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                     2L, 2L, 2L),
                                   .Label = c("eng", "scot", "wale"), class = "factor"), 
               edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                               .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"),
               lungfunction = c(45L, 
                                23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 
                                90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 
                                70L, 69L, 90L),
               ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
                          8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 
                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
                          9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
               no2_quintile = structure(c(1L, 
                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                          3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                          3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                          4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                          5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
                                        .Label = c("q1", "q2", 
                                                   "q3", "q4", "q5"), class = "factor")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                              -100L))
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, `sjPlot` is not currently capable of this. You can suggest this as a new feature on [Github](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot). The only other idea I have (that I was not able to execute successfully) is to take part `plot_model` objects using `ggplot_build` to extract the lines, colors, etc. and then rebuild the plot from scratch, incorporating all plot elements into one plot. Another option is to use [cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) to put the plots side by side, but it wouldn't look like your desired plot.